# Separation of variables method

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Hi I am trying to solve the following

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy}{x^2-1}$$ with boundary condition $y=1$ at $x=0$.

I use the method of separation of variables:

$$\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{2x}{x^2-1}dx$$

$$\ln (y)=\ln(x^2-1)+c$$

Then I got stuck because the solution says that $y=1-x^2$. Can anyone give me a hand with this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\exp(\ln (y)) = \exp(\ln(x^2-1)+c) \iff y = C(x^2 - 1).$$ Now use your boundary conditions to determine $C$.

$1 = C(-1) \iff C = -1$. So the solution is $$y = -1(x^2 - 1) = 1 - x^2.$$

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I have a question about what you said: why                 exp(ln(y))= exp(ln(x^2+1)+c) is equal to y=c(x^2-1)? The c is not in the ln so I thought that it will be like this y=x^2+1+exp(c)

Comment: The C comes from $$\exp(\ln(x^2-1)+c) = \exp \ln(x^2-1) \cdot \exp c = e^c(x^2 - 1) = C(x^2 -1)$$ I use the capital C to denote that it represent a different constant than little c.  Remember $e^{a + b} = e^ae^b$.

Comment: Oh I didn't noticed the capital C. OK now it make sense. Thanks again